# PowerShell executing .bat files with in the same session

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am installing a software in silent mode using PowerShell. Installation was done successfully but when I am trying to execute few batch files I am getting some exceptions.

> Could not find the files for the given pattern. The system can not find the specified path.

My command inside my PowerShell:

```
$inst_path = \\My installed drive (c:\program files\mysoftware\)
& $inst_path\start-service.bat install
```

But when I closed the PowerShell ISE and executing the same command it is working without any exceptions, so can someone help me overcome this?

Comment: What, pray tell, would the `some exceptions` be?

Comment: The problem I feel is with PowerShell session, error is not consistent when  I close the ISE and re-executing the script I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a double slash in the path to the bat file, both the `$inst_path` variable and the path you construct.

You're trying to call `c:\program files\mysoftware\\start-service.bat` - which is going to fail.

Try this instead:

```
$inst_path = "c:\program files\mysoftware"
& "$inst_path\start-service.bat" install
```